# find command moves files but then files become inaccessible

Tags: unix, find, exec, ls, mv

I ran the following command in a parametrized version of a script:
Script1 as

```
Nooffiles=`find $1 -mmin $2 -type f -name "$3"|wc -l`
if test $Nooffiles -eq 0
then
exit 1
else
echo "Successful"
find $1 -mmin $2 -type f -name "$3" -exec mv '{}' $4 \;
fi
```

The script1 works fine. It moves the files from $1 directory to $4. But after it moves the files to the new directory, I have to run another script like this:
Script2 as

```
for name in `find $1 -type f -name "$2"`
do
filename=`ls $name|xargs -n1 basename`
line=`tail -1 $filename | sed "s/Z/Z|$filename/"`
echo $line >> $3;
echo $filename | xargs -n1 basename;
done
```

Here, script2 is reading from the directory where the files were moved to by the previous script, script1. They exists there in that directory since the previous moving script worked fine. 'ls' command displays them. But the above script2 says:

```
File.txt: No such file or directory
```

Despite ls shows them in the directory, I am getting an error message like this.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you reading the files from the correct directory? Are you missing any slashes?

Comment: Have you tried the `-depth` option of find?

Comment: I am even able to see the outputs of the moved files from the new directory using  cat  command. 'ls' also works. Yet script2 says, they don't exist. By the way, what is  -depth  option?

Comment: The `-depth` option tells `find` to go "depth first". It will for instance find `a/b` then `a` instead of `a` then `a/b`. For instance, to delete CVS directories, you use `find -depth -type d -name CVS -exec rm -rf {} \;`: if you do not use `-depth` you will get warnings about `CVS: no such file or directory`.

Comment: Even with -depth option, it is not working. Script2 works on any file that I have made in that directory manually using cat command, but doesn't work on files moved from another directory by using Script1

Answer (score 1):

Your script really is a mess and please be aware that you should NEVER parse filenames (like the output from `ls`, or `find` without `-print0` option). See [Bash Pitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Apart from that, I think the problem is that in your loop, you truncate the filenames output from `find` with `basename`, but then call `tail` with the base filename as argument, where the file really isn't located in the current folder.

I don't understand what you are doing there, but this is some more correct code that perhaps does next to what you want:

```
find "$1" -type f -name "$2" -print0 | while read -d '' name
do
    filename=`basename "$name"`
    tail -1 "$name" | sed "s/Z/Z|$filename/" >> "$3"
    echo "$filename"
done
```

But still, there are pitfalls in this script. It is likely to fail with queer filenames input from `find`. For example, if your filename contains characters that are special to `sed`. Or if at some point `$filename` is `--help` etc.etc.etc.

Comment: In script1, I move files from a directory to another if there is atleast 1 file in that directory(based on some conditions). For script2, every file in the directory read by script1 from where files are moved to another directory, has a special property that it contains jumbled data, but the last line is like 'Z|1|23|||||', i.e, Z|number|number||||(a set of | symbols follows). The last line is important, previous lines are not. I want to extract the last line of all files recursively, change it to 'Z|filename|number|number|||||||' and merge all into one file.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is with script1 or 2, but somehow they are not working sequentially, i.e. run script1 then script2.